# Is there a way to get the current Date in IOS (time not needed, accurate enough regardless of system date) using method that is not overkill?

Tags: ios, date

I use the current date (YYYY-MM-DD) in a critical part of my app, and I need the correct date independant of the set system date. So far, the only option that I found that WOULD work is using an NTP server like this one [here](https://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/).

Problem: This is complete overkill for my purposes as I can deal with a +- several hour inaccuracy of the date. I simply need a somewhat accurate datestamp at various points throughout the app. All of the devices using my app will be connected to the internet as well as GPS, etc. I would even be happy to find a simpler method of finding the current date that would only work on some select devices, just something. I am wondering if anybody knows of any other ways now that actual time accuracy is not so important.

EDIT: I need this date to be independent of device date because the user could easily change the device date rendering it inaccurate.

Thank you.

Comment: why do you think device time is inaccurate? Cell devices synchronize their time from cell towers. For example if you are travelling between time zones, cell phone automatically correct their times ... so I am not sure what you need. You could get json/xml from atomic clock on the web and use that as your baseline.

Comment: @SamBudda I am saying that the user can change the device time and date, and it is not possible for me to check if they have "Set Automatically" enabled on the device time settings. If I could check for that somehow, I would be more than happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use NTP, or at least a subset of NTP since you don't need that much accuracy, perhaps simply accepting the first value returned from the NTP server.

As an alternative, if you run your own web server, you could create a very simple server-side application that simply returns the date via HTTP/HTTPS. To prevent users from spoofing the server, you'd probably want to use HTTPS rather than HTTP although really clever users could still get around that issue by installing private certificates on the device or a network proxy.

Note that depending on a server means that your application won't run if there's no network available.

An alternative would be to use the system date routines as others have described, but write the date to either NSUserDefaults or, better yet, the device keychain. That way, your application can tell if the user turned the date backwards. There may be some edge cases you'd have to watch out for, though, like time zone changes.

Comment: That makes sense. I did not think of that last method using date routines, which might work, but I probably will end up using the most basic NTP client I can find.

Answer (score -1):

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD"];
    NSString *dateAsString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question because the user could set the date ahead or behind, rendering the device time inaccurate.

Comment: What? Settings -> General -> Date & Time -> Uncheck Set Automatically

Comment: Please read the question properly and answer within its constraints.

Answer (score -1):

I have this method in my Utilities class.

```
+ (NSString *)formattedDate {
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *todaysDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    return todaysDate;
}
```

I put it in the header for results like this:

```
NSString *gameNameHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p>&nbsp</p><h1>%@ Results</h1><h2>%@%@</h2>",GAME_NAME_TITLE,[Utilities formattedClientName], [Utilities formattedDate]];
```